# Store, Update, delete, preview the image

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve the image from DB even when clicked on refresh.

**Javascript function:**

```
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(50)
                        .height(50);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Now when i choose the file, i will get a small thumbnail, but when i refresh, there will be no image.
Functionality i'm trying to achieve,

- Upload a file, show a preview small. - which is done.
- When i refresh it has to be there, since i'm concentrating on only one ID at the moment.

This application is to store,update,delete an image[while previewing all the time in a small thumbnail]. I'm using `Normal PHP` here, where as the app is in `CodeIgniter`.

EDIT: **All need is to ECHO the last uploaded image src.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the file to the server, so when you refresh, you are just blowing away all of the JavaScript variables that are holding the data.

Comment: OK, i did a insert of image name to the server. But how to do i read to back on the in html?
i believe i just have to put the src. but the src should be dynamically echo on to '<img src='here'> right?

Comment: Your server response needs to return the location of where the file was saved to. Then insert that as the src value.

Comment: +1 TYVM. So, i did `select *` in my view file and echo the imgname with src. Yup, all fine now.